# botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (UnauthorizedOperation) when calling the DescribeInstances operation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3, amazon-iam

I am trying to filter out instances in AWS by matching particular tag added in EC2 instance. For this I have created new IAM role with following limited permissions :-

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:DescribeInstances",
                "ec2:StopInstances"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:ec2:<aws-region>:<aws-id>:instance/*"
            ],
            "Condition":{
                "StringLike":{
                    "aws:ResourceTag/Name" : ["sample_type_*"]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I read about [collections](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/collections.html) in boto3 and implemented following filter function to find the instances :-

```py
ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2')
instance_name_prefix = "sample_type_"
filter_list = [
            {"Name": "tag:Name", "Values": [f"{instance_name_prefix}*"]},
            {"Name": "instance-state-name", "Values": ["running"]}
        ]
running_instance_list = ec2.instances.filter(Filters=filter_list)
```

But this throws me following error :-

```sh
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (UnauthorizedOperation) when calling the DescribeInstances operation: You are not authorized to perform this operation.
```

I tried to look for dependent actions for `DescribeInstances` in AWS [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/service-authorization/latest/reference/list_amazonec2.html) where it is shown to be not dependent on other actions.

Can someone point out where it is wrong ? Would appreciate any hint on this.

Thanks

Comment: The docs only list `ec2:Region` as valid condition key: you cannot condition on the tag for `DescribeInstances`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most listing operations are either allowed or are not allowed, there is no middle ground and no Conditions that can be evaluated. Interacting with the resources that get listed is then obviously dependent on further IAM permissions, but not the listing itself.

That is the case here. `ec2:DescribeInstances` cannot be restricted with `Conditions` other than the `ec2:Region`.

Comment: This worked for me :-

{
            "Sid": "VisualEditor3",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:DescribeInstances"
            ],
            "Resource": ['\*']
        },
        {
            "Action": [
                "ec2:StopInstances"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:ec2:<aws-region>:<aws-id>:instance/*"
            ],
            "Condition":{
                "StringEquals":{
                    "ec2:ResourceTag/<key-name>" : "<key-value>"
                },
            }
        },

Answer (score 0):

You are not able to access your EC2 instances using Lambda function. To get the authorization you have to add one policy in your AWS Lambda function. Edit your Lambda function role and add AmazonEC2ReadOnlyAccess policy.